# CS50P Felipe’s Taqueria: What does input of EOF halts program mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, cs50

It shows input of EOF halts program, expected exit code 0, not 1

Is there anyone who can explain what it means, and what changes I need to make?

```
menu = {
"Baja Taco": 4.00,
"Burrito": 7.50,
"Bowl": 8.50,
"Nachos": 11.00,
"Quesadilla": 8.50,
"Super Burrito": 8.50,
"Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
"Taco": 3.00,
"Tortilla Salad": 8.00
}

total = 0

while True:
    try:
        x = input("Item: ").title()
        if x in menu:
            total += menu\[x\]
            print(f"Total: ${total:.2f}")
    except EOFError:
        print()
        break
```

Using break, pass, and using KeyError.

Comment: Please correct code indentation in the `while/try/except` block.

Comment: It says: when the tester runs the program and makes the input end right away, your program should have an exit code of 0, but when your program runs, the exit code is 1 instead. It **is correct** that the program halts and that has **nothing to do with** the problem that the tester is reporting to you. In order to make sure, do you understand what an *exit code* is? Do you understand what `EOF` is?

Comment: (I didn't put that in an answer because if that is the only problem, then it is a problem with understanding English, not a problem with programming.)

Comment: I haven't tried running it through check50 in this state, but if that's the entirety of your code, the problem may simply be that you aren't generating the required output at all - After the EOF causes you to call `break`, your program just ends, therefore Pytest (run by Check50) reports a failure

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Linking this as a duplicate of "Exit Codes in Python" may not be entirely correct.  There's an abstraction level here in that the exit code of 1 is actually coming from Pytest being run by an automated grading system, not by this program itself.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety I see. In that case we need more information, and I don't think OP is in a position to supply it - are you familiar with the assignment?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes.  After every entry by the user, the program is supposed to print the running total price.  If the program provided here is OP's entire program, none of that output is included, so Pytest is likely reporting it as an error. Adding an explicit return 0 couldn't hurt, but the lack of the output required by the assignment is the more obvious problem to me.  [Problem Description](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/3/taqueria/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me. I added "else: pass" which solved the issue. I am not entirely sure yet, why this happened to be the solution. 

English is not my native language and i just started to learn python, so i defiantly lack a deeper understanding of basic concept like exits code, but I will read up on it.